# angular 10 - load component in other component

Tags: angular

In AngularJS it was possible to loading components with $compile in template.

I try to do this with Angular 10 like this:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentRef} from '@angular/core';
import { LoginFormComponent } from '../../component/login-form/login-form.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-on-boarding',
    templateUrl: './on-boarding.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./on-boarding.component.sass']
})
export class OnBoardingComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target: ViewContainerRef;


    private readonly componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver;

    constructor(componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
        this.componentFactoryResolver = componentFactoryResolver;
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(LoginFormComponent);
        const component = this.target.createComponent(factory);
        console.log(factory);
        console.log(component);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

    }

}
```

Template './on-boarding.component.html':

```
<div #container></div>
```

But nothing happens. No error, no component loading in #container.

Comment: which version of angular are you using? also are there errors in the console when you do this?

Comment: angular: 10.0.6 - no, there are no errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the child with `#container` ist just the half work. You will need to include your child component correctly. In case your child looks close to this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-container',
    ...
})
```

Then your parent's template should look like this:

```
<app-container #container></app-container>
```

Further reading: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

I have a component called "on-boarding". In this I want to load dynamically other components like "step1" or "step2"...

I dont' want to load all possible components in "on-boarding"

```
<app-step-1 *ngIf="..."></app-step-1>
<app-step-2 *ngIf="..."></app-step-2>
<app-step-3 *ngIf="..."></app-step-3>
```

When I can use templates with ViewChild, then it can be a solution, but I don't know, if thats possible.